# Using Local Network with samba

Tags: networking

I have 2 machines, destop PC and Netbook, both running ubuntu 14.04. Samba is installed on both and I have set directories to local network share with guest access. In order to enter data into a libreoffice calc document on the netbook from the PC with a better screen and keyboard.

I can access and edit .ods on the PC from the netbook but not the other way round! .txt files are fine both ways.

But I can if I boot to windows on the PC

This seems to apply only to .ods, .xls, .odt & .doc files in any directory.
  html, jpg, txt etc. are OK.

Libre office is 4.2.8.2 on the netbook and 4.4.0.3 on the PC.

This also applies to ods formats created on the pc and transferred to the netbook, so I still think it's a ubuntu rather than a libreoffice problem. If I stick the files on a usb stick everything is fine so why not over the network? if I open one with gedit it reports

"The file you opened has some invalid characters. If you continue editing this file you could corrupt this document.
You can also choose another character encoding and try again."

but his seems to be true of any office document. on either machine.

If I drag and drop it into LibreCalc I get

"Object not accessible.
The object cannot be accessed
due to insufficient user rights."

But I can copy files in both directions so what other permissions are there? I think I'll ask this of Libreoffice.

Any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround and will mark this as Solved.

In order to achieve my whole objective I have to use a proprietary piece of s/w which requires windows so I've already got a VirtualBox to run this. I therefore added libreoffice and links to the shared folders of the remote machine so I can now achieve the whole operation using the VB.

Does'nt explain why I can't do the editing form Ubuntu but hey life's short.